# Infinite loop in an array stack

Tags: java, arrays, stack, infinite-loop

I'm trying to implement a stack using an array to reverse sound files. Something is looping infinitely, and, after several hours of trying, I can't seem to figure out what it is.

Here is my stack:

```
import java.util.EmptyStackException;
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ArrayStack 
implements DStack {
    private int size = 0;
    private static int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 10;
    private Double ArraySt[];


    public ArrayStack(){
        ArraySt = new Double[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
        for(int i = 0; i < DEFAULT_CAPACITY; i++){
            ArraySt[i] = 0.0;
        }
        size = ArraySt.length;
    }


    public boolean isEmpty(){
        boolean empty = true;
        if(ArraySt != null) {
            empty = false;
        }

        return empty;

    }
    public void push(double d){
        if(size == ArraySt.length){
            increaseCapacity();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        ArraySt[i] = d;
        }
    }

    public double pop(){
        double popped = 0;
        boolean empty = isEmpty();
        if(empty == true){
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i > size; i--){
            popped = ArraySt[i];
            ArraySt[i] = null;
        }

        return popped;

    }

    public double peek(){
        boolean empty = isEmpty();
        if(empty == true){
            throw new EmptyStackException();
        }
        double stackTop = pop();
        return stackTop;

    }
//  private Double[] increaseCapacity(){
//      int arrayLength = ArraySt.length;       
//      int newCapacity = ArraySt.length*2;
//      Double[] increaseArray = new Double[newCapacity];
//      for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
//          Double k = ArraySt[i];
//          increaseArray[i] = k;
//          
//      }
//      return increaseArray;
//  }

    private void increaseCapacity(){
        int newCapacity = ArraySt.length;
        ArraySt = Arrays.copyOf(ArraySt, newCapacity);

    }
}
```

Here is the client program:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

/**
 * Read a .dat file and reverse it.
 * 
 * @version CSE373, 14sp
 */
public class ReverseRedux {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 3) {
            System.err.println(" Incorrect number of arguments");
            System.err.println(" Usage: ");
            System.err
                    .println("\tjava Reverse <stack type> <input file> <output file>");

            System.exit(1);
        }

        boolean useList = true;
        if (args[0].compareTo("list") == 0)
            useList = true;
        else if (args[0].compareTo("array") == 0)
            useList = false;
        else {
            System.err.println("\tSaw " + args[0]
                    + " instead of list or array as first argument");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            //
            // Set up the input file to read, and the output file to write to
            //
            BufferedReader fileIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[1]));
            PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter(args[2])));

            //
            // Read the first line of the .dat file to get sample rate.
            // We want to store the sample rate value in a variable,
            // but we can ignore the "; Sample Rate" part of the line.
            // Step through the first line one token (word) at a time
            // using the StringTokenizer. The fourth token is the one
            // we want (the sample rate).
            //
            StringTokenizer str;
            String oneLine;
            int sampleRate;
            String strJunk;

            oneLine = fileIn.readLine();

            str = new StringTokenizer(oneLine);
            strJunk = str.nextToken(); // Read in semicolon
            strJunk = str.nextToken(); // Read in "Sample"
            strJunk = str.nextToken(); // Read in "Rate"

            // Read in sample rate
            sampleRate = Integer.parseInt(str.nextToken());

            //
            // Read in the remainder of the file on line at a time.
            // The values in the first column are thrown away.
            // Place values from the second column on the stack.
            // Stop reading if we reach the end of the file.
            //

            DStack s;
            if (useList)
                s = new ListStack();
            else
                s = new ArrayStack();
            String timestep;
            double data;

            int count = 0;
            while ((oneLine = fileIn.readLine()) != null) {
                if (oneLine.charAt(0) == ';') {
                    continue;
                }
                str = new StringTokenizer(oneLine);

                // Read in time step value from first column
                timestep = str.nextToken();
                // Read in data value from second column
                data = Double.parseDouble(str.nextToken());
                s.push(data);
                count++;
            }

            System.out.println(count + " samples in file");

            //
            // Print the data values to output .dat file.
            // First, output the header line:
            // "; Sample Rate <sample rate>"
            //
            fileOut.println("; Sample Rate " + sampleRate);

            // Since the first column consists of numbers which start
            // at 0 and increase by 1/sampleRate every time slice, we'll
            // just use numSteps to recalculate these numbers.
            int numSteps = 0;

            // Finally, we print the values in reverse order (by popping
            // them off the stack). The first column consists of numbers
            // which start at 0 and increase by 1/sampleRate per row, so
            // we'll use numSteps/sampleRate to recalculate the appropriate
            // values. Print a tab for uniform spacing.

            while (!s.isEmpty()) {
                fileOut.println((double) numSteps / sampleRate + "\t" + s.pop());
                numSteps++;
            }

            //
            // Close the files
            //
            fileIn.close();
            fileOut.close();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.err
                    .println("Error opening/reading/writing input or output file.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.err.println(nfe.toString());
            System.err.println("Error in file format");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use an ArrayList? Then you don't need to worry about managing the size of your array.

Comment: ArrayList would cause massive boxing. edit: nvm, this code also boxes.

Comment: Moreso, why not just use a stack?

Comment: man, this code is weird. nothing ever updates `size`. `push` seems to overwrite everything. that loop in `pop` is hella fishy.

Comment: **WHOA**! `peek` calls `pop`!

Answer (score 0):

`isEmpty()` never returns false. The only things that ever assign to `ArraySt` are in the constructor (`new Double[DEFAULT_CAPACITY]`) and in `increaseCapacity` (`Arrays.copyOf(ArraySt, newCapacity)`). I assume neither will set it to `null`.

The "print the values in reverse order" part is looping forever, I'd guess.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is buggy. It will always return 0.

```
    public double pop(){
    double popped = 0;
    boolean empty = isEmpty();
    if(empty == true){
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }
    for(int i = 0; i > size; i--){
        popped = ArraySt[i];
        ArraySt[i] = null;
    }

    return popped;

}
```

Also, the array will never be null and empty due to the bugs in your code. Hence, looping forever.
Why don't you use LinkedList or ArrayList? Especially LinkedList is appropriate candidate here.